# H-bridge servo circuit design

Tags: h-bridge, servo

I have bought several servos from Aliexpress, namely the DS3235SG. Since a few the servo-boards burned up and replacement is not available, I went through the process of reverse engineering the circuit. Disclaimer: I have no expertise on electronics and my understanding is very basic.

I have created schematics and I do not understand why the P-channel MOSFETs get to have their signal amplified whereas the N-channel MOSFETs do not.

Has this any particular reason? If it's simply an oversight by the Chinese manufacturer for whatever reason, should I, in my new design, add amplifiers for the N-channel MOSFETs too, or even remove the P-channel signal amplifiers? It seems to work without amplifiers for the N-channel ones.

[image: simplified schematics]
[image: updated schematics]

[image: updated circuit pic]

EDIT: the red line is the path from the STM8-IC to the amplifier to the PMOS on the backside. When i looked up the amplifier part (J6 SOT23 = S9014) one datasheet said it was a signal amplifier and i did not look into it any further, now other datasheets describe it as "PNP Small Signal Transistor is designed for general purpose and switching amplifier applications."
What function would it have?

Comment: Just buy OpenSservo boards. Your PMOSFET  question is because MOSFETs are controlled by the gate-source voltage DIFFERENCE. The logic produces voltages relative to ground. The low-side NMOS has their source connected to gnd. The high-side PMOS does not. It's like you are on the 2nd floor in a building and need a 2m ladder. The 2m ladder is useless if it's sitting on the first floor. You need the top to be 2m above the 2nd floor, not the first floor.

Comment: This is basic H-bridge stuff so you should just read on getting real H-bridges  to work. Specifically high-side drive when NMOS are used and when PMOS are used. Might want to read on how to use NMOS and PMOS as a switch first though. Remember...controlled by the gate-source voltage DIFFERENCE.

Comment: The circuit for the PMOS devices is incorrect. The "amplifiers" would be used to pull the gates of the high side elements to GND, And where do the 330 ohm resistors connect?

Comment: The *signal amplifiers* look somewhat unlikely - they may be *level shifters*, which the n-channel switches don't need. Where are the P-channel source resistors going to?

Comment: @PStechPaul you are right I uploaded the unfinished version on accident, I have updated my post with the proper schematics and an actual image of the circuit board if that helps.

Comment: @greybeard I am honestly lost with this particular part , it's for sure a amplifier but what is it supposed to amplify and why. I have fixed the schmetics, could have another look at it please.

Comment: The S9014 is actually an NPN Darlington device, which is used to drive the gates of the high side MOSFETs. The emitter goes to GND. https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NextGen%20Components%20PDFs/S9014.pdf

Comment: Please check: the collector is routed to the via (and probably to the P-channel FET's gate on the flipside. That would be just your regular (inverting) common emitter level shifter.

Comment: (@PStechPaul where did you get *Darlington*?)

Comment: (Why not power the STM8S from filtered 5 V? Its core runs off an internal regulator either way.)

Comment: you two are totally right, pin 2 and 3 of S9014 should be switched. 

To sum it up: S9014 is used to switch the PMOSFETs off. Why do the NMOSFETs not need a similar switching device. I do notice that PMOS is connected to V5 and NMOS to GND, is that the reason?
@greybeard This servo can be driven with up to 7.4volts, in my case 5V are sufficient.

Comment: `S9014 is used to switch the PMOSFETs off` No. The 330 Ω resistors are use to remove charge from the P-channel MOSFETs' gates, the NPNs are used to charge to nearly -5 V to turn them on. They don't seem to be needed as level shifters as the STM8S seems to have at least some *true open drain outputs*. Guessing: for sheer current driving capacity.

Comment: @greybeard I was looking at another datasheet that showed a Darlington, but looking closer it is made from two devices. However, datasheet shows hFe as high as 1000, which seemed high for a single device. https://www.utmel.com/components/s9014-transistor-pinout-datasheet-and-circuit?id=623